# moving an entry form the end of table to the top

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using mySql  and I have a record with is in end of the table.  I want to bring it to the top of the table. How can move it? I mean there are entries at top of the table, how can i replace ids of both the entries with each other.

I want to do this because i want to move the last item to the start of the list, so that it appears first on my website.

thanks

Comment: There is no such thing as "*the end of the table*" in the relational model. Rows in a relational table do ***not*** of any "order"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suppose a simple ORDER BY in the select query will not satisfy your needs, so here is a way to physically replace row with id = 123 with row id = 1 assuming your table has more than 123 rows

```
update table_name set id=(select max(id)+1) from table_name where id=123;
/* this will move the last record to somewhere temporary */

update table_name set id=123 where id=1 ;
/* this will move the first row to the place of the row that was at the bottom */

update table_name set id=1 where id=(select max(id) from table_name);
/* moving from temporary row to the first of the table */
```

Comment: are you sure that it works? i get `#1093 - You can't specify target table 'users' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: both `update table_name set id=(select max(id)+1 from table_name) where id=123;` and `update table_name set id=1 where id=(select max(id) from table_name);`, i get error #1093, you can't update a table if you reference it in a subquery

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom order by:

```
select * from mytable
order by if(id = 1234, -1, id); -- change "1234" to id of row you want first
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want to change the structure of your data in the DB...

Take the array of your result set and do this in PHP.  If you're only changing order of one item in list, don't do it in SQL.

```
  $resultSet = $connection->query("some query");
  if(is_array($resultSet)){

      //pop the last item in array out of array
      $itemToMove = array_pop($resultSet);

      //insert the item at the start of the array
      array_unshift($resultSet, $itemToMove);
   }
```

Comment: Or, *do* it in SQL, but using an `ORDER BY` clause on your query, not by actually altering the database records themselves.

Comment: @DanJ  If he only wants the last item moved you wouldn't want to use `order by`.  `order by` would change the entire ordering of the result set.

Comment: Nothing wrong with using a conditional ORDER BY clause to order a certain record differently from the rest of the results. But if the only reason for doing so is presentation, then, you're right, you may as well do it in the presentation layer.

Comment: Thanks both. Yes i only want to do it for changing the presentation.

Can you also tell me if it is possible to move only one record in database to the top, using SQL? If i use ORDER BY clause, will it not reverse the order of all the items, and i am wanting only to move the very last item to the top?

Comment: Ray@  If i want to use your code, where will i run it? Can i run it somewhere in mySQL interface?  My website is hosted with soem webhosting service.  I am not too sure what window or something i need to open to run that code ?

Comment: what if i need to permanaently move the last item to the top, wont it be better to change the structure in the datasaseb, how will i do it. Each item has an ID, if i give the last item the same id as of the first item, an error will generate??

Comment: -1 This is only useful if he's using php, and there's no suggesting of that, so this answer is not helpful

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have something like `SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY id` and you want to bring want to make id 50 id 1. The following two statements should help:

```
UPDATE data SET id = id + 1 ORDER BY id DESC;
UPDATE data SET id = 1 WHERE id = 51;
```

Note that you need to update id 51 in the second statement as you added 1 to every id with the first statement.

If your SELECT does not contain an ORDER clause (as it should) also do this:

```
ALTER TABLE data ORDER BY id;
```

Hope this helps.

Regards

TC

Comment: thanks. I liked your method.  Can you clarify:

UPDATE data SET id = 1 WHERE id = 51;  --- it's changing last id value to 1

UPDATE data SET id = id + 1 ORDER BY id DESC;  -- is it changing 1st id value to the last?   if yes in this v r not telling change value 1 to 51, i dont understand?

Comment: The order by on the update just ensures that you never have the same id twice and MySQL complains by adding to the highest value first and to the lowest value last.

Answer (score 0):

If just need to show the last row at the top of the table, you could use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
ORDER BY id = (select id from your_table order by id desc limit 1) DESC, id
```

The subquery returns always the last id (you could also use `max(id)`), if the condition is met it's value it's 1, otherwise it's 0 hence the `DESC` so the row where the condition is met is moved first.

If you need also to show the id swapped, this could be an idea:

```
SELECT IF(id=1,
          (select max(id) from your_table),
          if(id=(select max(id) from your_table),1,user_id)) as id
FROM your_table
ORDER BY id
```

(first `id` is always `1`? if not, you have to replace both `1` with `select min(id) from your_table`)

But do you really want to swap the values, and not just show the rows in a different order? In MySql unfortunately it is not possible to do this:

```
UPDATE your_table SET id = (select max(id) from your_table) + 1 WHERE id = 1
UPDATE your_table SET id = 1 WHERE id = (select max(id) from your_table) - 1
UPDATE your_table SET id = id-1 WHERE id = (select max(id) from your_table)
```

(and, btw, if the min value is different than 1 it would get lost) because you can't update a table if you are referencing it in a subquery. I posted another solution that works and uses just joins!

Answer (score 0):

I already posted a solution using just SELECT, but i wasn't sure if it was possible to use an UPDATE, but i found how to do it.

I know it is a little weird, but i think it's the only solution that always works and that always swaps first `id` with last `id` using just one query and without knowing their values:

```
update
  your_table
  inner join (select max(id) as max from your_table) mx
  inner join (select min(id) as min from your_Table) mn
  on your_table.id = mx.max
  or your_table.id = mn.min
set id=if(id=mx.max,mn.min,mx.max)
```

or if you just need to put last one at the top, and move every other row dows, something like this might work:

```
update your_table
  inner join (select max(id) as max from your_table) mx
  inner join (select min(id) as min from your_table) mn
set id=if(your_table.id=mx.max,mn.min,id+1)
```

but notice that this might not work if id is primary key, if that's the case, i don't think it could be done in just one pass.